# How to autoconnect to Ethernet network when restarting?

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet

Firstly, I hope this hasn't been covered elsewhere, I have searched but haven't found this particular problem.

I updated to 12.04 a while back and though I now thoroughly regret that decision, I'm able to live with 12.04 and all it's odd little quirks.

The one problem that I would like to fix is this. I have a small network, using a router modem which stays on most of the time. If the computer is switched off, when it is switched on again I have to click on "auto Ethernet" in "Network" in order to get on the internet. It then works fine.

Previous versions just connected automatically on restart. When 12.04 says it is unable to connect, other computers on the network are able to connect.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

To turn your problem, you can do this:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and type `gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces` and enter.

Add the following lines if not already present:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Note: Change eth0 for your network device. To view this open terminal with `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
ifconfig
```

This should be enough to solve your problem.